# Improper unity display

Tags: unity, gnome

Today,after updating 12.04 LTS and Openoffice to 4.0.1, I noticed some missing programs in the menu, Software Center K3b.  I reinstalled them and I shut down my computer.  Later when tried to log on the GUI kept bringing me back to the login screen.  I added the gdm package and now can log on to the "Gnome session", but get a faliure to launch message with the ubuntu and ubuntu 2D settings.  When in the "Gnome session", the icons on the right side the screen and the bar across the top show not the selected wallpaper, except seen as a background in shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Unity

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Restart, log into Gnome (assuming you've already installed it), and reinstall Ubuntu Desktop

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```